How prominent are centipedes in Green Hell?
Okay, this might be a bit of an odd question, but bear with me. I'm quite interested in playing Green Hell and would like to try it out as I generally enjoy survival gameplay. However, I also have a serious primal fear of centipedes and similar arthropods (I can live with spiders, though, if they're not excessive). And since the Amazon is notorious for featuring all kinds of living creatures, I was worried they might be a part of the game and after quickly consulting the Wiki with squinted eyes, my suspicions were confirmed.
Now I would like to know how prominent of a feature they actually are in the game. Can they possibly be somehow avoided even or are they maybe restricted to a specific area or chapter within the story mode? Do I have to stay constantly on the edge of worrying that I might possibly encounter one of those creatures, possibly in a..."dynamic" or surprising scenario even? It is a bit of a fuzzy question, but basically how much trouble is the game to someone with such a fear of these creatures and how can I best prepare for unwelcome surprises?
(I don't mind spoilers for game content or story plotlines, but due to the nature of the question, please try to avoid explicit imagery.)

I do realize the irony of wanting to play a survival game and then schewing away due to some "whimpy" reason. However, that's afterall why I play survival games rather than venturing into the outdoors for real. ;-)

This is a totally valid reason to ask such a question! Don't feel like you need to justify yourself! (Unfortunately, I am not familiar with the game)

It looks like the game contains scorpions at least -- not sure if that's on your list or not.

They're pretty unavoidable, unfortunately. When you pick up a large leaf or stick, there may randomly be a large centipede crawling on it. You then have to drop whatever you've picked up, leaving the centipede on the ground for you to kill. As far as I've been able to tell, you cannot see the centipede before picking things up.
